# how to write a PromQL with regex and binary operator

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I can use `avg({__name__="model1_request_keys_qps", project="test_project"}/{__name__="model1_qps", project="test_project"})` to calculate kps(keys per second) for model1.

Now I want to get top10 models based on kps, something like this:
`topk(10, avg({__name__=~"(.*)_request_keys_qps", project="test_project"}/{__name__=~"\1_qps", project="test_project"}) by \1)` #\1 means one model_name.
But it doesn't work with PromQL.

Could anyone provide a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution with label_replace:
topk(10, sum(label_replace({**name**=~".*_request_keys_qps", project="test_project"}, "model_name", "$1", "**name**", "(.*)_request_keys_qps")) by (model_name) / sum(label_replace({**name**=~".*_qps", project="test_project"}, "model_name", "$1", "**name**", "(.*)_qps")) by (model_name))